# Changing content of page with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a website I build on a MEAN stack. My main navigation has about 10 pages which are controlled by ngRoute. One of these navigation items has a lot of inside links to pages where the content is almost the same everywhere. The only thing I need to change on each page is a cityname and phonenumber and some other small stuff. So my question is: Can I make only one page where I change content on each link-click in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom directive:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_custom_directives.htm

Basically this allows you to create a configurable 'template' by adding a custom attribute to an element of your HTML (you define the attribute name, as the name of your custom directive). You can add the custom data that you need to each view you need to display, by passing it as data to the custom directive.